# How to print struct variables in console?

Tags: struct, go

How can I print (to the console) the `Id`, `Title`, `Name`, etc. of this struct in Golang?

```
type Project struct {
    Id      int64   `json:"project_id"`
    Title   string  `json:"title"`
    Name    string  `json:"name"`
    Data    Data    `json:"data"`
    Commits Commits `json:"commits"`
}
```

Answer (score 1214, accepted):

To print the name of the fields in a struct:

```
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", yourProject)
```

From the [`fmt` package](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/):

> when printing structs, the plus flag (`%+v`) adds field names

That supposes you have an instance of Project (in '`yourProject`')

The article [JSON and Go](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go) will give more details on how to retrieve the values from a JSON struct.

---

This [Go by example page](https://gobyexample.com/json) provides another technique:

```
type Response2 struct {
  Page   int      `json:"page"`
  Fruits []string `json:"fruits"`
}

res2D := &Response2{
    Page:   1,
    Fruits: []string{"apple", "peach", "pear"}}
res2B, _ := json.Marshal(res2D)
fmt.Println(string(res2B))
```

That would print:

```
{"page":1,"fruits":["apple","peach","pear"]}
```

---

If you don't have any instance, then you need to **[use reflection](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)** to display the name of the field of a given struct, [as in this example](http://play.golang.org/p/JKHjPu3cgB).

```
type T struct {
    A int
    B string
}

t := T{23, "skidoo"}
s := reflect.ValueOf(&t).Elem()
typeOfT := s.Type()

for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
    f := s.Field(i)
    fmt.Printf("%d: %s %s = %v\n", i,
        typeOfT.Field(i).Name, f.Type(), f.Interface())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there is one more thing. 
My JSON files are related to an API... therefor I dont want to set the Id or Name, I just want to get it over the API and print it in console. How can I do that?

Comment: @fnr If you have a JSON document, you would need to unmarshall it, before being able to print its field.

Comment: Just a note, this works nicely with pointers as well. It won't print out the address, but it will add a `&` in front of your output.

Answer (score 215):

I want to recommend [go-spew](https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew), which according to their github "Implements a deep pretty printer for Go data structures to aid in debugging"

```
go get -u github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew
```

usage example:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
)

type Project struct {
    Id      int64  `json:"project_id"`
    Title   string `json:"title"`
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Data    string `json:"data"`
    Commits string `json:"commits"`
}

func main() {

    o := Project{Name: "hello", Title: "world"}
    spew.Dump(o)
}
```

output:

```
(main.Project) {
 Id: (int64) 0,
 Title: (string) (len=5) "world",
 Name: (string) (len=5) "hello",
 Data: (string) "",
 Commits: (string) ""
}
```

Answer (score 203):

my 2cents would be to use `json.MarshalIndent` -- surprised this isn't suggested, as it is the most straightforward. for example:

```
func prettyPrint(i interface{}) string {
    s, _ := json.MarshalIndent(i, "", "\t")
    return string(s)
}
```

no external deps and results in nicely formatted output.

Comment:  Short and sweet. You can replace `"\t"` with `"  "` if you want space indenting instead

Comment: Of note, [`Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) only serializes the exported fields of a struct -- it's perfect for maps though.

Comment: Definitely not a viable solution as non-exported fields AND exported fields with ignored JSON tag (i.e. json:"-") will not be included.

Comment: @GoForth define "viable" -- your comment is dismissive, assumes too much and in general not helpful; the OP did not include any constraints in his question: he provided a struct (all exported and tagged fields) and wanted to know how to print it. exactly how is the simple proposed code `definitely not a viable solution` to their query?

Comment: @mad.meesh By not viable I meant that while it works for OP's struct as all fields are exported and mapped to JSON, this solution is not a generally viable solution for all structs.

Comment: @GoForth well.. couple things. first, again, your comment isn't helping nor pertaining to the OP. and second, we'll just have to -- respectively -- agree to disagree. i _do_ think this solution is viable _in the general case_. where i will agree with you is that there are _some_ cases where this solution has to be _modified_. but _in general_ it gets you there.

Comment: if you use unix you can pipe it to jq for a better-looking JSON  output

Answer (score 52):

I think it would be better to implement a custom stringer if you want some kind of formatted output of a `struct`

for example

```
package main

    import "fmt"

    type Project struct {
        Id int64 `json:"project_id"`
        Title string `json:"title"`
        Name string `json:"name"`
    }

    func (p Project) String() string {
        return fmt.Sprintf("{Id:%d, Title:%s, Name:%s}", p.Id, p.Title, p.Name)
    }

    func main() {
        o := Project{Id: 4, Name: "hello", Title: "world"}
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", o)
    }
```

Answer (score 27):

```
p = Project{...}
fmt.Printf("%+v", p)
fmt.Printf("%#v", p) //with type
```

Comment: `fmt.Printf(%#v, p)` , throws me `main.struct` with `struct type`  what is the difference between `"%#v"` and `"%+v"` @cokebol

Comment: "%+v" : This will give you the un-marshalled value along with their field-names.
"%#v" : This will give the values along with their type/signatures. For eg:  p := Project{Id: 4, Name: "hello", Title: "world"}
output for "%+v":  {Id:4 Title:world Name:hello}
output for "%#v":   main.Project{Id:4, Title:"world", Name:"hello"}

Answer (score 27):

Alternatively, try using this function `PrettyPrint()`

```
// print the contents of the obj
func PrettyPrint(data interface{}) {
    var p []byte
    //    var err := error
    p, err := json.MarshalIndent(data, "", "\t")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s \n", p)
}
```

In order to use this you do not need any additional packages with the exception of `fmt` and `encoding/json`, just a reference, pointer to, or literal of the struct you have created.

To use just take your struct, initialize it in main or whatever package you are in and pass it into `PrettyPrint()`.

```
type Prefix struct {
    Network string
    Mask    int
}

func valueStruct() {
    // struct as a value
    var nw Prefix
    nw.Network = "10.1.1.0"
    nw.Mask = 24
    fmt.Println("### struct as a pointer ###")
    PrettyPrint(&nw)
}
```

It's output would be

```
### struct as a pointer ###
{
    "Network": "10.1.1.0",
    "Mask": 24
}
```

Play around with the code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/YZn4hHXYdw).

Answer (score 17):

I suggest u use `fmt.Printf("%#v\n", s)` , It will print golang type at the same time

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

type student struct {
    id   int32
    name string
}

type Project struct {
    Id      int64   `json:"project_id"`
    Title   string  `json:"title"`
    Name    string  `json:"name"`
}

func TestPrint(t *testing.T) {
    s := Project{1, "title","jack"}
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", s)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", s)
}
```

result:

```
{Id:1 Title:title Name:jack}
main.Project{Id:1, Title:"title", Name:"jack"}
```

Answer (score 11):

I recommend to use [Pretty Printer Library](https://github.com/kr/pretty). In that you can print any struct very easily.

1. Install Library

   https://github.com/kr/pretty

or

```
go get github.com/kr/pretty
```

Now do like this in your code

```
package main

import (
fmt
github.com/kr/pretty
)

func main(){

type Project struct {
    Id int64 `json:"project_id"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Data Data `json:"data"`
    Commits Commits `json:"commits"`
}

fmt.Printf("%# v", pretty.Formatter(Project)) //It will print all struct details

fmt.Printf("%# v", pretty.Formatter(Project.Id)) //It will print component one by one.

}
```

Also you can get difference between component through this library and so more. You can also have a look on library [Docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/kr/pretty) here.

Comment: Would be helpful to see the example of the output generated by `pretty.Formatter`

Answer (score 10):

I like [litter](https://github.com/sanity-io/litter).

From their readme:

```
type Person struct {
  Name   string
  Age    int
  Parent *Person
}

litter.Dump(Person{
  Name:   "Bob",
  Age:    20,
  Parent: &Person{
    Name: "Jane",
    Age:  50,
  },
})
```

`Sdump` is pretty handy in tests:

```
func TestSearch(t *testing.T) {
  result := DoSearch()

  actual := litterOpts.Sdump(result)
  expected, err := ioutil.ReadFile("testdata.txt")
  if err != nil {
    // First run, write test data since it doesn't exist
        if !os.IsNotExist(err) {
      t.Error(err)
    }
    ioutil.Write("testdata.txt", actual, 0644)
    actual = expected
  }
  if expected != actual {
    t.Errorf("Expected %s, got %s", expected, actual)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, it might be handy to print the struct as valid Go code (the `go/ast` equivalent). For this purpose, https://github.com/hexops/valast does a great job:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/hexops/valast"
)

type ProjectData struct {
    Title   string `json:"title"`
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Data    string `json:"data"`
    Commits string `json:"commits"`
}

type Project struct {
    Id   int64        `json:"project_id"`
    Data *ProjectData `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    p := Project{
        Id: 1,
        Data: &ProjectData{
            Title:   "Test",
            Name:    "Mihai",
            Data:    "Some data",
            Commits: "Test Message",
        },
    }
    fmt.Println(valast.String(p))
}
```

Output:

```
go run main.go 
Project{Id: 1, Data: &ProjectData{
        Title:   "Test",
        Name:    "Mihai",
        Data:    "Some data",
        Commits: "Test Message",
}}
```

Comment: Sadly, it looks like `go-spew` hasn't received any updates in a long time. I believe it might have been abandoned. For now, it's still functional though.

Answer (score 5):

When you have more complex structures, you might need to convert to JSON before printing:

```
// Convert structs to JSON.
data, err := json.Marshal(myComplexStruct)
fmt.Printf("%s\n", data)
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/tetsuok/4942960

Answer (score 3):

Visit [here](https://gist.github.com/hygull/0fbc428dc77bef4a665b19d598f865d8) to see the complete code. Here you will also find a link for an online terminal where the complete code can be run and the program represents how to extract structure's information(field's name their type & value). Below is the program snippet that only prints the field names.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

func main() {
    type Book struct {
        Id    int
        Name  string
        Title string
    }

    book := Book{1, "Let us C", "Enjoy programming with practice"}
    e := reflect.ValueOf(&book).Elem()

    for i := 0; i < e.NumField(); i++ {
        fieldName := e.Type().Field(i).Name
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", fieldName)
    }
}

/*
Id
Name
Title
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example demonstrating the use of format specifiers `%d`, `%t`, and `%s` for each built-in type in Go like: `int`, `string`, `bool`, `struct`, and `interface`.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

// Define a struct
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

// Define an interface
type Describer interface {
    Describe() string
}

// Implement the Describer interface for Person
func (p Person) Describe() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Name: %s, Age: %d", p.Name, p.Age)
}

func main() {
    // Integer
    intVar := 42
    fmt.Printf("Integer %%d: %d\n", intVar)

    // Boolean
    boolVar := true
    fmt.Printf("Boolean %%t: %t\n", boolVar)

    // String
    strVar := "Hello, Go!"
    fmt.Printf("String %%s: %s\n", strVar)

    // Struct
    person := Person{Name: "Alice", Age: 30}
    fmt.Printf("Struct %%+v: %+v\n", person)

    // Interface
    var describer Describer
    describer = person
    fmt.Printf("Interface %%s: %s\n", describer.Describe())
}
```

In this example, each type is printed using the specified format specifiers.

`%d is for integers`

`` %t` is for booleans ``

`` %s` is for strings ``

`` %+v` is for structs, showing field names along with values ``

I hope it would be helpful for you. For more details, you can read this blog [Exploring Built-in Types in Go](https://medium.com/@kamruljpi/exploring-built-in-types-in-go-formatting-and-printing-f467160a431)

Answer (score 1):

There's also [go-render](https://github.com/luci/go-render), which handles pointer recursion and lots of key sorting for string and int maps.

Installation:

```
go get github.com/luci/go-render/render
```

Example:

```
type customType int
type testStruct struct {
        S string
        V *map[string]int
        I interface{}
}

a := testStruct{
        S: "hello",
        V: &map[string]int{"foo": 0, "bar": 1},
        I: customType(42),
}

fmt.Println("Render test:")
fmt.Printf("fmt.Printf:    %#v\n", a)))
fmt.Printf("render.Render: %s\n", Render(a))
```

Which prints:

```
fmt.Printf:    render.testStruct{S:"hello", V:(*map[string]int)(0x600dd065), I:42}
render.Render: render.testStruct{S:"hello", V:(*map[string]int){"bar":1, "foo":0}, I:render.customType(42)}
```

Answer (score 1):

i suggest to use `json.Unmarshal()`
i try to print the id with this hope its helpfull:

```
var jsonString = `{"Id": 1, "Title": "the title", "Name": "the name","Data": "the data","Commits" : "the commits"}`
var jsonData = []byte(jsonString)

var data Project

var err = json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &data)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return
}

fmt.Println("Id :", data.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `%+v` with `fmt.Printf`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Project struct {
    Id      int64   `json:"project_id"`
    Title   string  `json:"title"`
    Name    string  `json:"name"`
    Data    Data    `json:"data"`
    Commits Commits `json:"commits"`
}

func main() {
    yourProject := Project{
        Id:    1,
        Title: "Project Title",
        Name:  "Project Name",
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", yourProject)
}
```

To have fine-grained control over the output format, like include or exclude fields and format them use this:

```golang
fmt.Printf("Id: %d, Title: %s, Name: %s\n", yourProject.Id, yourProject.Title, yourProject.Name)
```

docs: https://pkg.go.dev/fmt

Answer (score -1):

very simple 
I don't have the structure of Data and Commits So I changed the

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Project struct {
    Id      int64   `json:"project_id"`
    Title   string  `json:"title"`
    Name    string  `json:"name"`
    Data    string  `json:"data"`
    Commits string  `json:"commits"`
}

func main() {
    p := Project{
    1,
    "First",
    "Ankit",
    "your data",
    "Commit message",
    }
    fmt.Println(p)
}
```

For learning you can take help from here : https://gobyexample.com/structs

Answer (score -1):

If you want to write in a log file, as I was searching previously. Then you should use:

```
log.Infof("Information %+v", structure)
```

**Note:**: This will not work with ***log.Info or log.Debug***. In this case, "%v" will get printed, and all the values of the structure will be printed without printing the key/variable name.